# Foundation 6 (6.2.3) Equalizer stops working when I try to use optional configurations

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, foundation-equalizer

I've got a site that relies on foundation.

Everything works great, until I add the optional javascript configurations documented [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/equalizer.html#optional-javascript-configuration).

Specifically:

```
equalize_on_stack: false
```

That give me this error:

```
  foundation.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: We're sorry, object is not a valid parameter. You must use a string representing the method you wish to invoke.
```

This is in my footer file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).foundation({
        equalizer : {
            equalize_on_stack: false,
        }
    });
});
```

And the elements I'm targeting look like this:

```
<div class="box-group" data-equalizer>
    <div class="medium-6 columns text-center" data-equalizer-watch>
        stuff and things        
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns text-center" data-equalizer-watch>
        things and stuff        
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery is loaded in the header and equalizer *does* work if I initialize it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

Maybe I'm missing something simple. If anyone out there can take a look and help me figure out why "equalize_on_stack" doesn't work, I'd really appreciate it.

**=== SOLVED IT ===**

Thanks to Shoaib Iqbal, I was able to get it working.

Turns out, I was referencing the foundation 5 documentation for version 6.

I was able to solve the problem by adding:

```
 data-equalize-on-stack="false"
```

like so:

```
<div class="box-group" data-equalizer data-equalize-on-stack="false">
```

All I needed in my footer was this:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Comment: Please include your code when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you are NOT passing the plugin name, it should have `equalizer` in it

```
$(document).foundation({
  equalizer : {
    equalize_on_stack: false,
  }
});
```

Comment: I've updated the site and my post with your correction. Still getting the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: Which version of Foundation you are using?

Comment: #6 -- downloaded roughly two weeks ago. Edit: 6.2.3

Comment: The docs link and the code you posted is of Foundation 5, use the Foundation 6 code.

Comment: Oh my gosh... How did I miss that. :'(

It's all working now, Thanks for the help.