# Updating Rails Foundation-rails gem 5 to 6, datepicker does not work, JS error on page load

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

Updating legacy Rails application to the new version of Foundation (gem `foundation-rails` from 5.5.3.2 to current version 6.1.2.0). Removed specification of gems versions for `sass`, `sass-rails`, and `foundation-rails`. Ran `rails g foundation:install`.

Not working `rails-assets-foundation-datepicker` gem, used with `datagrid`, and chrome developer tools shows an error:

> foundation.core-fcefb93….js?body=1:282 Uncaught TypeError: We're sorry, 'object' is not a valid parameter. You must use a string representing the method you wish to invoke.

**application.js**

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require foundation
    //= require evil-blocks
    //= require chosen-jquery
    //= require foundation-datepicker
    //= require_tree .

    $(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

**application.css**

```
    /*
     *= require_self
     *= require normalize-rails
     *= require chosen
     *= require foundation_and_overrides
     *= require foundation-datepicker
     *= require_directory .
    */
```

**libs.js.coffee**

```
    $ ->
        $(document).foundation
            equalizer:
                equalize_on_stack: false

        $('#filter select').chosen
            allow_single_deselect: true

        $('.date-picker').fdatepicker
            language: 'ru'
            weekStart: 1
            closeButton: false
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Datepicker usage example:

```
    filter :start_date, :date, header: I18n.t('date_start'),
      html_options: {class: 'date-picker'} do |value, scope|
        scope.where('notices.created_at > ?', value)
    end
```

Excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647992/foundation-6-6-2-3-equalizer-stops-working-when-i-try-to-use-optional-configur).

```
     $(document).foundation
        equalizer:
            equalize_on_stack: false
```

This was the the old code not working with Foundation 6. You need add `data-equalize-on-stack="false"` in elements like so

```
     <div class="box-group" data-equalizer data-equalize-on-stack="false">
```